# Calling Worker inside a long loop

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Sorry if duplicate, but couldn't find my exact case. I'm playing around Web Worker and is pretty interesting. I was testing different cases and hit this.

Main :

```
var myWorker = new Worker("WK.js");

for (var i = 0; i <= 1000000000; i++) {
    myWorker.postMessage(i);
}

myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
    alert(e.data);
}
```

Worker :

```
var sum = 0;
        self.onmessage = function (e) {
        if (e.data == 1000000000) { postMessage("done" + sum); }
        sum += e.data;
    }
```

On the worker script, I'm just summing up the passed values and post back the sum once done. The problem I face is, the above code crashes my browser(all) for this number(~1000000000) however if I move that loop to worker script, it works fine. So is there a limit for the number of postMessage calls per duration? Please note I do know this is bad code, just for testing.

Comment: What exactly does "crashes" refer to, what did you experience? Did it just hang (as expected)?

Comment: IE went blank for some seconds and closed :( while chrome reported a crash. Didn't check Firefox though.

Comment: The same would happen when not using web workers. Web workers exist to *avoid* creating long loops in GUI thread.

Comment: 'The same would happen when not using web workers' no. You can test yourself. Like I said, I'm just playing around workers and I do know this is bad code. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser may not have crashed. The problem is you have a later for loop that gets executed in the main ui that if the browser. So basically the browser is busy busy ruining your code, and can't find to any user input, I.e. It is busy, and generally this results in No responding' message in windows. The rain you don't get this in a worker is simply because that code executes in a completely separate thread (non ui).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a memory / garbage collection issue. You're posting a billion messages, each at least the size of an integer, which I think in Javascript is stored just as all other numbers, so 8 bytes. Ignoring any extra overhead per message, this means that it needs to allocate at least 8gb of memory.

I  have to admit a level of ignorance of the garbage collector, but it might not be able to keep up with a billion objects using 8gb of memory allocated in a short amount of time.

> So is there a limit for the number of postMessage calls per duration

I suspect yes, although perhaps it's not clear what you mean by "duration" here.

Comment: Could be but in that case an 'out of memory' would have been thrown right? I guess it fills up the event cycle queue (some limit) since each postMessage is considered a separate event instead of one. I could be wrong.